# Custom HTML parameters for component

Tags: java, tapestry

When you use standard `t:pagelink` component you can pass arbitrary number of custom HTML attributes like `class` or some `data` attributes:

```
<t:pagelink page="somepage" data-somedata="test">link name</t:pagelink>
```

And they will be included in generated `a` tag:

```
<a href="/somepage" data-somedata="test">link name</a>
```

This does not work for components created by me. When I have:

```
<t:misc.custompagelink page="somepage" data-somedata="test">link name</t:misc.custompagelink>
```

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="/somepage">link name</a>
```

How to mimick the behaviour of standard `t:pagelink` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this, both easy:

1) Read and follow the "Informal Parameters" section at http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html

2) Have your component class extend Tapestry's "Any" component (http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Any.html)

Comment: Howard, you might want to elaborate, particularly since I added that useful scenario to Any's javadocs a year ago (TAP5-2298) based on a discussion on the mailing list.

Comment: Subclassing Any is acceptable, but any option that doesn't involve subclassing is preferable. I've learned to love just a little bit of boilerplate.